# Are there P problems with no known polynomial-time algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, polynomial-time

As the title says, I'm just curious if there are any problems with polynomial-time algorithms, but where no polynomial-time algorithm for it is currently known? Of course, this question would be trivial if the only method of showing a problem is in class P is by providing an algorithm. However, there can also be non-constructive proofs, which is why I ask.

A quick Google search turned up nothing. Also, this is my first question on this site, so my apologies if I'm breaking any rules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any problems in $P$ which we do not know any $P$ algorithms?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92087/are-there-any-problems-in-p-which-we-do-not-know-any-p-algorithms)